# Do I need ADT and NDK for android if I already have it as plugins for Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, adt

I'm trying to make and compile a software called linphone which I hope to push to my phone.   The README file says that before i can run the make command, I must have ADT and NDK installed.

I know I have the ADT and NDK plugin installed for Eclipse, because i was able to make some basic android apps and push to my phone.

So when I went to my linphone directory and typed "make" in terminal, it said I did not have android SDK installed.

Do I really need to re-download android adt and ndk and install it in such a way that it is accessible via bash?  Or is there a short cut to make my bash recognize that Eclipse already has all these tools installed, and just re-use it to make and compile linphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I really need to re-download android adt and ndk and install it in such a way that it is accessible via bash? Or is there a short cut to make my bash recognize that Eclipse already has all these tools installed, and just re-use it to make and compile linphone?

No, you should be able to simply add the locations where you have the Android SDK and NDK installed to your bash PATH. In Eclipse you can find this by looking at **Window > Preferences > Android > SDK Location** and **Window > Preferences > Android > NDK > NDK Location**.

As to how to add the these locations to your PATH, please refer to [this question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path).

**UPDATE**: Just noticed in the README for linphone that you need to add some of the subfolders for the SDK:

> add both 'tools' and 'platform-tools' folders in your path

So you will need to adjust accordingly.